# How can I programmatically find out current Azure Storage Account count and limit?

Tags: azure

I'm writing some code that will automatically provision new ARM storage accounts, and as part of it, I need to check how close I am to the [max number of storage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits).  I can't find anything concrete by searching (only [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/), which is a bit of a dead-end).  I'm operating entirely with HTTP calls (no .NET Azure library dependencies).

Effectively, I'm trying to find the ARM way to get the `MaxStorageAccounts` and `CurrentStorageAccounts` properties of this classic endpoint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh403995.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Found the right URL to hit by taking the `Get-AzureRmStorageUsage` cmdlet and running it through ILSpy to decompile:

```
http://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription ID}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/usages?api-version=2016-01-01
```

Not sure why I couldn't find any references to it online.